# I want to add CSRF token to each post request made on login page

Tags: php, csrf

I want to add the CSRF token to each POST request made on the login page.

I am new to PHP and tried implementing CSRF token but my page doesn't load because of my silly mistakes. 
I want to make vulnerable SQLi page with CSRF protection that is why I am trying to write vulnerable code. 
I want to add CSRF token to this page. My login page is working as expected just want to add CSRF.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if($_POST['submit']) {
    include_once('connection.php');
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id,username,password FROM users where username = 
        '$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if($query) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $userId= $row[0];
        $dbUserName = $row[1];
        $dbPassword = $row[2];
    }
    if($username == $dbUserName && $password == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
        header('Location: user.php');
    }
    else {
        echo "<b><i>Incorrect credentials</i><b>";

    }
      }

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name = "username" placeholder="Enter username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password here">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If the token is valid then the user is allowed to log in the application else give an error "Token is not valid". In case the token is correct then the user will move to the new page.

Comment: No use for `CSRF` protection when you are wide open for [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) though

Comment: @darkbee I understand your point but in my test case I need to put CSRF token. I want to demonstrate SQLi with CSRF protection. It would be great if you can help me in implementing CSRF on the above page.

Comment: Did u actually already look up `CSRF`? I don't see any attempts of introducing the token inside your code at this point

Comment: right now you are coding in raw PHP, maybe you install Laravel to try to implement this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf